# Jenkins Build failure due to mysql Database not found error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jenkins, build

The project includes express.js server to run a mySql commands. The build failed due to the following reason

```
Failures:
22:49:03 1) Display DB to User Parsing Failure
22:49:03   Message:
22:49:03     Uncaught exception: Error: ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database 'demo'
```

Comment: Are you certain mysql is running?

Comment: No. I wanted to know is there a way to include or introduce a db into jenkins.